# UITableview remove the cell in visible regision

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I customize my own tableview, which contains several sections and each section contains only one row. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath, I store the indexPath.section as a property of the cell.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     KEShowcaseTableViewCell *cell = (KEShowcaseTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sectionCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if( cell == nil ){
        cell = [[KEShowcaseTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:sectionCellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.section = indexPath.section;

    cell.horizontalTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

However, after I scroll up and down several times on my tableview, I found the cell in didEndDisplayingCell store different value of indexPath.section from the parameter indexPath.section.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   if( cell.section != indexPath.section ){
       NSLog(@"something wrong!");
   }
}
```

And I will find out my tableview remove the cell that is still in visible region.

Where should I check about this tableview?

Comment: Can you please post the code where `cellforrowatindexpath`?

Comment: Where do you set the `cell.section` property?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is, that this cell is already being reused in the tableView. So the cell that you are actually seeing is not the one that dissapeared, but the one that was reused and is being showed in the table.

If you want to get the cell, you have to manually call cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I agree with the cell may has already being reused...
However, the didEndDisplayingCell function would let this cell be removed in my tableview...
This would let the tableview being empty in visible area

Comment: What do you mean with "let this cell be removed"? If you want to remove a cell you need to use indexPaths

Comment: I mean the cell object "A" could be reused to another indexPath(such as it was first used in section:0, and being reused in section:3). However, after the didEndDisplayingCell function(section:0), the view on section:3 will be disappear...   It would let my tableview show the wrong result.